# Event Trigger not firing when EventRelation record is inserted using data loader

Tags: trigger, event

I have a trigger on Event that gets called before update and after update. The trigger essentially computes the next meeting date and the last meeting date for each account related to that event (using eventrelation).

My problem is that this trigger is not being called when an EventRelation is inserted using data loader. The EventId of the EventRelation is set to the Event and the Event's WhoCount and LastModifiedDate are being updated accordingly but the update triggers are not be called.

Any ideas?

Comment: triggers fire on DML of the target object (`Event`) yet you are updating `EventRelation`. You need something that executes DML on the `Event` parent to cause its triggers to fire

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Trigger on EventRelationChange then go to Setup>Change Data Capture and enable the EventRelation Entity. Salesforce will "publish" an Event when any EventRelation record is Inserted, Updated or deleted (basically it insert a EventRelationChange record), that in turn calls your EventRelationChange Trigger which will have access to all the EventRelation fields. Better than using is a Schedulable/Batch convo.